# Javascript not summing correctly?

Tags: jquery

This is what I have in scripts.js

```
var player1score = 0;
if (currentPlayer === 1) {
    $("ul#player1scorelist").each(function() {
        player1score = parseInt(player1score) + parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $("#player1totalscore").text(player1score);

    // ...
}
```

It's supposed to get each child in player1scorelist and return the sum of the numbers in the child nodes. Instead it combines the 2 numbers.

For example:

- 3
- 5
- 6

shows as 356.

running a typeof on player1score shows integer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the code in a snippet?

Comment: first thing, dont use `parseInt` overload without a radix. secondly `ul#player1scorelist` cannot have a each loop. id should be unique. did you mean `ul#player1scorelist li`

Comment: I don't know what's causing your specific issue, but: 1) don't call `parseInt ` on `player1score` - it's already an integer 2) don't call `parseInt` without a radix param (google the docs) 3) calling `.each` on a collection that was created with a `#` selector is kind of useless--a `#` selector will only ever produce 1 element (if it finds anything at all)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is parsing the text of a parent element containing three numbers. The resulting text is 3 numbers that look like an integer. For example:

```
$('<ul><li>3</li><li>5</li><li>6</li></ul>').text() // = "356"
```

Make sure you are looping over the elements that actually contain the numbers you want to sum as suggested by other commenters, e.g.

```
$("ul#player1scorelist li").each(...)
```

Comment: ah, the correct issue. duh. :) nice catch. working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/7af9rLfj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is parsing the parent element ie ul, so you get all the values of the ul ie 356. You can use the sum some other way

```
var sum = $('#player1scorelist li').toArray().reduce(function(sum,element) {                        
    return sum + Number(element.innerHTML);
}, 0);
```